# Linewrap in GUI Emacs in Linux

Tags: linux, emacs, emacs23, xterm

When I run term mode in emacs GUI, I have issues with line wrapping. It runs fine when I am running emacs in xterm. When there is an output that has a very long line, it is all displayed on the same line, with my prompt.  When I launch emacs in xterm, and then go to term mode, it behaves properly, wrapping the long line.

I run:

`aaronjg@aaronjg-desk:~$ echo $PATH`

and get.

`aaronjg@aaronjg-desk:~$ usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/aaronjg/kde/bin:/usr`

Comment: I sometimes have this problem if I'm using xterm (which you are) and I adjust the width of the window using the mouse. I assume because xterm can't figure that out correctly all the time.

Comment: drysdam: I tried resizing the window, and it unfortunately did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in .emacs:

```
(setq overflow-newline-into-fringe nil)
```

Here's where it comes into play in term.el:

```lisp
(defun term-window-width ()
  (if (featurep 'xemacs)
      (1- (window-width))
    (if (and window-system overflow-newline-into-fringe)
        (window-width)
      (1- (window-width)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main variable to control that behaviour in Emacs is `truncate-lines`. Check its value. Maybe you have a configuration file that sets it to true. In that case you should be able to change that by adding this to your personal configuration file:

```
(set-default truncate-lines nil)
```

Comment: I tried toggling truncate line mode, and it didn't help.  The weird thing is it seems completely dependent on the fringe being absent.

Answer (score 0):

To cause emacs to "wrap" lines as you type you have a couple of choices:

- Turn on auto-fill-mode (a minor mode) use `M-x auto-fill-mode` which will hard wrap your lines. Wrapping is controlled by the value of the `current-fill-column` variable
- Turn on longlines mode (also a minor mode) with `M-x longlines-mode` which will soft wrap you lines. Here wrapping is controled by the variable `fill-column`, and there are other interesting features such as hard-newline exposure under the control of `longlines-show-hard-newlines`.

Comment: That also didn't seem to work. I get the same results as before, where the line is just wrapped over on itself.

Comment: @aaronjg: Ah...in a normal terminal I would be suspicious of your TERM variable. Try `printenv TERM` *in the emacs shell*, then try googling with the result and "emacs" and "wrap". Might get somewhere.